# Escape quote with font family

Tags: html, css, fonts

I want to use font-family CSS

```
<div style="font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif"> Hello world! </div>
```

For the font-family "Times New Roman", should I escape the quotes? Or can I use it without quotes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use single quotes:

```
<div style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif"> Hello world! </div>
```

or alternatively (Thanks [@Matt](//stackoverflow.com/questions/16493394/escape-quote-with-font-family/16493409?noredirect=1#comment23672544_16493409)):

```
<div style='font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif'> Hello world! </div>
```

Comment: Just wanted to note that this works both ways, i.e. you could alternatively do this: `style='font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif'`

Comment: This turns into Inception when your HTML is already inside of single quotes in JavaScript. At that point, I guess you would use backslash to escape the quotes.

Answer (score 9):

Within an attribute value in HTML, you cannot use delimiter of the value inside the value as such, for rather obvious reasons: in `style="font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif"`, the second quote terminates the value, so that there is just the attribute `style="font-family:"` followed by something that constitutes a syntax error.

There are several ways around this.

1) The delimiter can be written using an entity reference like `&quot;`, e.g.

```
style="font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;, Times, serif"
```

2) You can use a different delimiter, namely a single quote, if the value contains a double quote:

```
style='font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif'
```

3) Depending on the nature of the attribute value, it might be possible to use another character inside the value. In this case, since the value is CSS code and CSS accepts single quotes too, you can write:

```
style="font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif"
```

4) Depending on the nature of the attribute value, it might be possible to omit the character inside the value. In this case, since the quoted string in the value is a font name in CSS and since [the quotes are not required](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-family-prop) (contrary to popular belief) in a simple case like this, you can write:

```
style="font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif"
```

Finally, you can avoid this problem by using an external style sheet or at least a `style` element instead of writing CSS code in an attribute.

Comment: The 4th option doesn't seem to work for me and as far as I can tell, only works if the font family name can be parsed as an identifier (specifically cannot contain spaces). Also when I try to use the first option (entity reference), visual studio 2013 complains about "unexpected character sequence in property value", but I don't know if this is a bogus warning

Answer (score 0):

Use single quote

```
<div style='font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif'> Hello world! </div>
```